# How to select the last record from MySQL table using SQL syntax

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with several records. There is an id field. I would like to select the record with the most recent id (i.e. the highest id).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: In order of performance, the answer from @Luiz Vid is better?

Answer (score 13):

You could also do something like this:

```
SELECT tb1.* FROM Table tb1 WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(tb2.id) FROM Table tb2);
```

Its useful when you want to make some joins.

Answer (score 8):

User order by with `desc` order:

```
select * from t
order by id desc
limit 1
```

Comment: You forgot that OP said wanted "the" record with highest id -- should have used limit.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT MAX("field name") AS ("primary key") FROM ("table name")
```

example:

```
SELECT MAX(brand) AS brandid FROM brand_tbl
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT   *
FROM     table
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT    0, 1
```

Comment: `LIMIT 1, 1` is equal to `OFFSET 1 LIMIT 1` therefore penultimate record will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following two:

```
1 - select id from table_name where id = (select MAX(id) from table_name)
2 - select id from table_name order by id desc limit 0, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 1
```

The `ASC` will return resultset in ascending order thereby leaving you with the latest or most recent record. The `DESC` counterpart will do the exact opposite. That is, return the oldest record.