# MySQL Query - Show Latest 3 Records with Order by Ascending

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there anyway to fetch **latest 3 comments** with **Order By id asc** ?

Here is my table Structure: **Table name: comments**

[image]

**Right Now I am using this Query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM `comments`
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 0 , 3
```

**But it returns in result, which is obvious :**

[image]

But I want to show latest 3 records , but in Ascending Order.
**Like this:**

[image]

Comment: Well written and documented question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select the last record from MySQL table using SQl syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659253/how-to-select-the-last-record-from-mysql-table-using-sql-syntax)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate of that, @djot! That's just about the 1 last record which is much simpler.

Comment: @markus Well not directly to this. But duplicate to hundreds of answers here that all show order direction `DESC` for Mysql.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use below code:

```
SELECT * 
   FROM (SELECT *
      FROM `comments` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 3) t
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

First you sort by descending id, and get 3 results, and then do ascending sort on id on these 3 results.

Answer (score 7):

```
(SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY id DESC limit 3 ) ORDER BY id ASC
```

Just reorder the DESC query with a second ORDER BY :)

Comment: Nice, simple and it works. I never thought of doing that before.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, it avoids a subquery.

Comment: awesome, took me quite a while to find this solution, thank you!! I must say, I don't really get why ```SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC, time ASC LIMIT 5``` is not workin?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM comments   
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 3
) t ORDER by id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from (select * from `comments` ORDER BY id desc limit 0,3) t
order by id asc;
```

Answer (score -3):

This should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM `comments`
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0 , 3
```

Comment: Make your answer a good answer by explaining why this will do it?

Comment: That will only work with his test data, but I bet it wont work with the real data!

Comment: @markus because it orders by comment and bottom-up so new ones comes first.

Comment: What if the last comment starts with A and the first comment starts with z ?

Comment: But in real world you need more columns to that table such as status to make it to disable and enable comment. Date Time field etc.

Comment: Upps ORDER BY id DESC should do it not comment. Thanks @Hanky웃Panky