# How can I SELECT the last row in a MySQL table ? I don't have any auto increment key

Tags: java, mysql

I want to SELECT the last row in a MySQL table. I don't have any auto increment key in that table.

```
public String getLastLeaveId() {
    try {
        Statement stmt  = getConnection();
        String sql="select leaveID from applied leave"; // here I want some logic that will fetch only leave_id from last row only
        stmt.execute(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

```
//Table Structure --->
(leave_id varchar(50) primary key,emp_id varchar(40),birthday varchar(20),anniv varchar(20),rh varchar(200),total int,foriegn key(emp_id) reference employee);
```

Comment: how do you define 'last'?

Comment: If it is in java then show your code

Comment: I am just writing a String sql query to be executed by statement and fetching the ResultSet.

Comment: can you show table structure.what is primary key and all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select the last record from MySQL table using SQL syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659253/how-to-select-the-last-record-from-mysql-table-using-sql-syntax)

Comment: @AJ In that question they are using auto increment key

Comment: Not possible... not on MyISAM or InnoDB engine. The storage engine cant give an   
guarantee
 
 that the records are returnd in the same order.

Answer (score 2):

Order descending on whatever column you're ordering now and do a `limit 0,1` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit ordering in a database table. If you don't have an auto-increment column, a date/time column, or some other column that follows a natural order when you insert rows, you're limited to using some other way of faking it.

You don't show a table structure in your question, nor do you state whether you're using MyISAM or InnoDB. MyISAM stores rows in order they're inserted (usually) so you can use something inneficient like `ResultSet.last()` from Java to get the last row, but if you're not using MyISAM you can't depend on that. InnoDB, the default storage engine, stores records in a more efficient B-Tree order, and does not retain the insert order at all, but rather stores records according to the primary key's order.

In short, you'll need to pick a field that has some natural order (or invent one) and order by that.

Answer (score 0):

Without having either a where clause and/or order by condition you can't fetch the last row in a query directly. You need to traverse through all the rows to stop before last row.

Only positive options I see are:

1. Select all rows. execute a `rs.last()` and then read it.
2. Use `order by desc` clause based on a column.
3. Define a virtual `row_num` on all selected rows and run a select
   with desc order on that row_num.
4. Execute two statements. One to find row count and the second to
   limit to fetch last row.

Pseudo example on 4th option above:

- int rowCount = result from "Select count(*) from my_table";
- String query = "select * from my_table limit " + ( rowCount - 1 ) +
  ", 1";
- rs = stmt.execute above query.
- read the only record, none but the last record, from rs, fetched.

Answer (score -1):

it's may be useful

```
   SELECT MAX(ID) FROM YourTable

   // Similarly, ORDER BY with LIMIT:

    SELECT ID FROM YourTable ORDER BY ID Desc Limit 1
```

Answer (score -2):

This is what you want.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```