# C#: How to get data from the last row in database? I'm using in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012

Need help in C# ( Visual Studio 2017 )

I want to get a data from my database from the last row or last inputted data.
My code is here..

```
            String query = "SELECT TOP(1) MessageNumber FROM ncslbpHighWay";
            SqlCommand SDA = new SqlCommand(query, AR);

            SqlDataReader data = SDA.ExecuteReader();
            if (data.Read())
            {
                textBox2.Text = data.GetValue(0).ToString();
            }
            AR.Close();
```

I already got the data but from the specific column at the top only. I don't know how to get the bottom value.
Also i tried the `DESC` but it doesn't work.

`String query = "SELECT TOP(1) MessageNumber FROM ncslbpHighWay ORDER BY COLUMN DESC";`

This is my first question here in Stackoverflow. I hope someone would help me on this.

Comment: What are you talking about that last record that came in?

Comment: How about `SELECT * FROM ncslbpHighWay ORDER BY COLUMN DESC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you could display the table structure.

Comment: What is the value in data.GetValue(0) or data??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your specified query below works for SQL Server for getting last value in table:

```sql
SELECT TOP(1) MessageNumber FROM ncslbpHighWay ORDER BY [ColumnName] DESC
```

However since you're mentioning MySQL tag (implying you're using MySQL instead of SQL Server), you need to use `LIMIT n` after `ORDER BY` instead, where n is the number of returned results, i.e. 1 for single result:

```sql
SELECT MessageNumber FROM ncslbpHighWay ORDER BY [ColumnName] DESC LIMIT 1

-- or using offset:
SELECT MessageNumber FROM ncslbpHighWay ORDER BY [ColumnName] DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

If you're using `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection` instead using standard `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`, you can write data retrieval like this:

```
using (MySqlConnection AR = new MySqlConnection())
{
    AR.Open();
    String query = "SELECT MessageNumber FROM ncslbpHighWay ORDER BY [ColumnName] DESC LIMIT 1";
    using (MySqlCommand SDA = new MySqlCommand(query, AR))
    {
        MySqlDataReader data = SDA.ExecuteReader();
        if (data.Read())
        {
            textBox2.Text = data.GetValue(0).ToString();
        }
    }
    AR.Close();
}
```

NB: I recommend you using ORM (e.g. Entity Framework) with [MySQL Connector .NET library](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) to enable LINQ functionality when managing database queries.

Similar issues:

[How to select the last record from MySQL table using SQL syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659253/how-to-select-the-last-record-from-mysql-table-using-sql-syntax)

[Select last row in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073923/select-last-row-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Considering your question below snippet can help you.

```
-- Method 01--
SELECT * FROM TestData where ID =(Select Max(ID) from TestData)

-- Method 02--
SELECT top 1 * FROM TestData order by ID Desc;
```

Here I have consider ID columns as Auto Increment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use orm. Things will become easy.