# How to get the last inserted record from a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I used

```
select * from equation_table order by type desc limit 1
```

But it returns 2nd record from the table.

Comment: Please include some data to make your question reproducible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Get most recent record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523374/mysql-get-most-recent-record)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an autoincrement **id** in your table which is names as id. then you can simply run below SQL to get last inserted record.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE id != 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: yes. But I write it for syntax purpose. Though we want only 1 record then 1 is enough.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM equation_table 
WHERE Eqtbl_id != 0 
ORDER BY Eqtbl_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You can find more by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659253/how-to-select-the-last-record-from-mysql-table-using-sql-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

if id is primary and autoincreament field then.

```
Select * from equation_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```